# regex in java extract a number

Tags: java, regex

i am getting started with regex in java and am trying to extract the number 99999 from a String which looks like:

```
<result name="response" numFound="99999" start="0">
```

Can you suggest me what can be the most efficient regex to achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a one-off case, you can use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes from `java.util.regex` package as follows and extract the value:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("numFound=\"([0-9]+)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<result name=\"response\" numFound=\"99999\" start=\"0\">");

if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Otherwise, it is strongly recommended to use a proper HTML Parser like [`Jericho`](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) to parse the HTML and read the attributes accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Vikdor. I actually tried something like this and that works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replaceAll()` to extract the part you want in just one line.

```
String number = input.replaceAll(".*numFound=\"(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

---

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "<result name=\"response\" numFound=\"99999\" start=\"0\">";
    String number = input.replaceAll(".*numFound=\"(\\d+).*", "$1");
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Output:

```
99999
```